# object required error vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

```
 Dim FSO As Object
    Dim FromPath As String
    Dim ToPath As String
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objSubFolder As Object
    Dim fil As File

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker) 'Choosing FromPath
        .Show
        FromPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker) 'Choosing ToPath
        .Show
        ToPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With


   Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(FromPath)
   For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
        **Set fils = fsoC.GetFolder(objSubFolder & "\").Files**

        For Each fil In fils
            If LCase(Right(fil.Name, 3)) = "zip" Then
               MsgBox "this is a zip file "
            Else
```

I'm getting object required error  in the marked row , and I do not understand why ? Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: `objSubFolder` is an object, but you need a string, try `fsoC.GetFolder(objSubFolder.PATH & "\").Files`

Comment: thank you, but it didn't help.

Comment: `fils` seems to be not declared, maybe that would help (`As Object` or `As Files`)

Comment: @RandySchuman Why do you think there is VBS too?

Comment: `fsoC` is not declared.

Comment: @MátéJuhász `Dim fil As File` is at the top ...

Comment: @davidPostill he uses Fils but declared Fil

Answer (score 0):

`fsoC` seems to be not declared / instanciated in your script. Maybe you would like to use `objFSO` again ?

*Edit :*

```
Sub test()
 Dim fils As Object
 Dim fil As Object
 Dim FromPath As String
 Dim ToPath As String
 Dim objFSO As Object
 Dim objFolder As Object
 Dim objSubFolder As Object

 With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker) 'Choosing FromPath
     .Show
     FromPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
 End With

 With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker) 'Choosing ToPath
     .Show
     ToPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
 End With


Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(FromPath)
For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
   Set fils = objFSO.GetFolder(objSubFolder & "\").Files

   For Each fil In fils
      If LCase(Right(fil.Name, 3)) = "zip" Then
         MsgBox "this is a zip file "
      Else
         MsgBox "NOPE"
      End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

This code works with the following folder :

```
A
-- A.1
---- test.txt
---- test.zip
```

Comment: Thanks , I forgot to set a variable at the beginning of the code you're right

Comment: Why do you declare ObjFSO and FSO but only use one of them?

Comment: I just update the object used at the marked line and add `fils` declaration. It was more of a copy/paste example than an clear code of the author.

I'll edit it. Thanks !

Comment: @netanel if this answered your question, please select the answer.